# Typescript how can I do {} as typeof Type

Tags: typescript

I have an app where I can auto generated a lot of apollo interfaces. They have very inconvenient names and I basically have the option to import them and use the types...

```
import {
  BaseQuery,
  BaseQuery_secondary as Secondary,
  BaseQuery_secondary_something_much_deeper_than as Tertiary,
} from 'types'
```

but this is very inconvenient. It would however be great if I could just import the BaseQuery types and then destructure the objects in my react components...

```
const { seondary } = data
const { tertiary, and, other, things } = secondary || {} as typeof secondary
```

since most graphql query items are nullable, I need to be sure that I am not destructuring null so I need a way to instantiate that type without importing the actual type definition manually. Is this possible?